# How come Go doesn't have stackoverflows

Tags: memory-management, stack, language-design, stack-overflow, go

I read in this presentation http://golang.org/doc/ExpressivenessOfGo.pdf  page 42:

> *Safe*
>
> *- no stack overflows*

How is this possible? and/or how does Go works to avoid this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a feature called "segmented stacks": every goroutine has its own stack, [allocated on the heap](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#goroutines).

In the simplest case, programming language implementations use a single stack per process/address space, commonly managed with special processor instructions called `push` and `pop` (or something like that) and implemented as a dynamic array of stack frames starting at a fixed address (commonly, the top of virtual memory).

That is (or used to be) fast, but is not particularly safe. It causes trouble when lots of code is executing concurrently in the same address space (threads). Now each needs its own stack. But then, all the stacks (except perhaps one) must be fixed-size, lest they overlap with each other or with the heap.

Any programming language that uses a stack can, however, also be implemented by managing the stack in a different way: by using a list data structure or similar that holds the stack frames, but is actually allocated on the heap. There's no stack overflow until the heap is filled.

Comment: Each thread has it's own stack, so "It causes trouble when lots of code is executing concurrently in the same address space (threads)." cannot be true.

Comment: A lot of this is incorrect, Go still uses the push/pop instructions (well, actually they don't but neither does GCC [mov off(%esp)]), it just sets the stack and stack base registers to a heap allocated stack.

Comment: Wow. I'd never heard of this. Great answer!

Comment: @dan_waterworth, @cthom06, I've been simplifying greatly. Will edit.

Comment: and stackless is a project to bring tasklets to python. tasklets being threads that start off with a small stack.

Comment: @dan_waterworth, the original aim of Stackless was to get rid of the "C stack": http://zope.stackless.com/index_old.htm I've removed the bit about Stackless as indeed they're not as anti-stack as they used to be.

Comment: I stand corrected, however in my defence, stackless's main feature is tasklets.

Comment: you can replace the stack of an executing thread from within the thread.

Comment: I don't think this is especially relevant to the "safe" quality, though.  Whether the frames are on a plain old stack, or allocated dynamically inside a heap, eventually you can run out.  If you overrun a object in a segmented stack, you can still cause security problems, just as if it was a heap overrun.

Comment: @poolie: stack overflow exceptions are a pain in C or C++. It forces you to manually create iterative versions of recursive functions, or like CLang did in the last two weeks move the execution to a separate thread... and that is if you can **foresee** the issue. In order to circumvent this, many people will simply set a large stack (where I work it's 8MB per thread), but this still involve tuning and guesswork. Not having to worry about the stack size adds safety (not security).

Comment: Based on the comments here, this answer needs a bit more. Segmented stacks are more than just heap allocated. The Go runtime ensures that the stack is large enough (see runtime·morestack) at the beginning of a function, and if it isn't, it allocates more space for the stack (if there isn't enough memory, it panics).

Comment: @poolie: this approach replaces the stack overflow exception with the general out-of-memory error. There's no way to get around that except inventing infinite memory. The difference is that with heap-allocated stacks, you have one memory area to worry about instead of one per thread.

Comment: I understand the benefit, I'm just not convinced that's what they meant by "stack overflow" in this context.  Incidentally, the benefit is somewhat diluted on 64-bit machines where there is such an abundance of address space to hold widely-spaced stacks: give them each 4GB and be happy.  (Obviously not all machines are 64 bit.)

Comment: Is "segmented stacks" the correct term to describe this? Shouldn't it be ["Heap-allocated Stack Frames"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ContinuationImplementation)?

Comment: @NoobSaibot Probably. The Go people have a bit of a habit of reinventing the wheel, and slapping on their own terms. (With pretty good results, though.)

Answer (score 5):

it uses a segmented stack. Which basically means it uses a linked list instead of a fixed size array as it's stack. When it runs out of space it makes the stack a little bigger.

edit:

Here is some more information: http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#goroutines

The reason this is so great is not because it'll never overflow (that's a nice side-effect), it's that you can create threads with a really small memory footprint, meaning you can have lots of them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they can "totally" avoid stack overflows. They provide a way to prevent the most typical programming-related errors to produce a stack overflow.

When the memory finishes there is no way to prevent a stack overflow.

Comment: but anyone that writes a program that overflows a heap based stack is doing it wrong.

Comment: and that is 90 % of people out there, that's why the designers of go tried to prevent this

Comment: 90% of people will overflow a *heap* based stack (one like go's)?

Comment: You can't really, by definition, over a heap-based segmented stack. A stack overflow is stack_growth->*collision*<-heap_growth. With segmented stacks its just out of memory. (and still not an overflow in Go, the allocator panics instead)

Comment: For the C language, the stack default size is 1 to 8 MB, this is usually much less than any computer memory. In fact it may forces you to avoid recursion, when recursion is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Even C can do it with a few constraints that basically affect the compiler.

It is an impressive feat of engineering but not of language design.

Comment: I don't have any. I basically invented the technique. With a bit of assembly and a bit of imagination you can too. It's not that hard.

Comment: Set the esp to somewhere in the heap?

Answer (score 0):

I think what they are referring to here is that access to arrays is always checked against the actual length of the array, thus disabling one of the most common ways by which C programs crash accidentally or are crashed maliciously.

For example:

```
package main

func main() {
    var a [10]int

    for i:= 0; i < 100; i++ {
        a[i] = i
    }
}
```

will `panic` with a runtime error when it tries to update the non-existent 11th element of the array.  C would scribble over the heap, and probably also crash but in an uncontrolled way.  Every array knows its length.  In some cases there will be scope for the compiler to optimize out the checks if it can prove they are not necessary.  (Or a sufficiently smart compiler could perhaps statically detect a problem in this function.)

Many of the other answers are talking about the memory layout of the stack but this is really not relevant: you can have heap overflow attacks too.

Basically Go's pointers should always be typesafe, with arrays and other types, unless you specifically use the `unsafe` package.

Comment: I think you're confusing buffer overflows and stack overflows. You're correct though.

Comment: What you describe is bounds checking, it has nothing to do with the stack overflows the OP asked about. Pascal does this too, but it is (in typical implementations) vulnerable to stack overflows.

Comment: I can't work out if the comment there is talking about a stack buffer overrun, or a stack overflow.  If I was describing the key features of Go (for an audience that knows C), I would certainly mention checked arrays before I mentioned nearly-unlimited-size stacks.  On the other hand this mention is in a section about concurrency, so perhaps they do mean you can add threads without giving them small stacks.