# Avoiding stack overflows by allocating stack parts on the heap?

Tags: c, recursion, stack, stack-overflow, heap-memory

Is there a language where we can enable a mechanism that allocates new stack space on the heap when the original stack space is exceeded?

I remember doing a lab in my university where we fiddled with inline assembly in C to implement a heap-based extensible stack, so I know it should be possible in principle.

I understand it may be useful to get a stack overflow error when developing an app because it terminates a crazy infinite recursion quickly without making your system take lots of memory and begin to swap.

However, when you have a finished well-tested application that you want to deploy and you want it to be as robust as possible (say it's a pretty critical program running on a desktop computer), it would be nice to know it won't miserably fail on some other systems where the stack is more limited, where some objects take more space, or if the program is faced with a very particular case requiring more stack memory than in your tests.

I think it's because of these pitfalls that recursion is usually avoided in production code. But if we had a mechanism for automatic stack expansion in production code, we'd be able to write more elegant programs using recursion knowing it won't unexpectedly segfault while the system has 16 gigabytes of heap memory ready to be used...

Comment: If you're writing critical code for a car, you probably don't have unbounded stack growth in the first place ;)

Comment: What is your question?  You can maintain your own stack in any language.

Comment: Yeah, that was just a joke. A better example would be a non-embedded application on a typical desktop computer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I want to use "automatic" variables and recursion in a language without having to using an explicit stack and manually simulate function calls!

Comment: [Go has such feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226964/how-come-go-doesnt-have-stackoverflows)

Comment: You can already control how big your threads' stacks will be at thread creation time with APIs like `CreateThread()` and `pthread_attr_setstacksize()` if you need the extra stack space (the main thread is a little trickier).  But increasing the stack size while a thread is running is practically impossible if you can't reserve the virtual address space at the bottom.  It might be theoretically possible in a GC'ed language where the runtime can fixup all pointers between objects, but even then it would be very high cost.

Comment: If you have finished a well tested application, you can set the stack size appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is precedent for it.

- The runtime for GHC, a Haskell compiler, uses the heap instead of the stack.  The stack is only used when you call into foreign code.
- Google's Go implementation uses segmented stacks for goroutines, which enlarge the stack as necessary.
- Mozilla's Rust *used to* use segmented stacks, although it was decided that it caused more problems than it solved (see [[rust-dev] Abandoning segmented stacks in Rust](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2013-November/006314.html)).
- If memory serves, some Scheme implementations put stack frames on the heap, then garbage collected the frames just like other objects.

In traditional programming styles for imperative languages, most code will avoid calling itself recursively.  Stack overflows are rarely seen in the wild, and they're usually triggered by either sloppy programming or by malicious input--especially to recursive descent parsers and the like, which is why some parsers reject code when the nesting exceeds a threshold.

The traditional advice for avoiding stack overflows in production code:

1. Don't write recursive code.  (Example: rewrite a search algorithm to use an explicit stack.)
2. If you do write recursive code, prove that recursion is bounded.  (Example: searching a balanced tree is bounded by the logarithm of the size of the tree.)
3. If you can't prove that it's unbounded, add a bound to it.  (Example: add a limit to the amount of nesting that a parser supports.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you will find a  *language* mandating this. But a particular *implementation* could offer such a mechanism, and depending on the operating system it can very well be that the runtime environment enlarges the stack automatically as needed.

Answer (score 2):

According to `gcc`'s documentation, `gcc` can generate code which does this, if you compile with the `-fsplit_stack` option:

```
-fsplit-stack
     Generate code to automatically split the stack before it overflows.
     The resulting program has a discontiguous stack which can only
     overflow if the program is unable to allocate any more memory.
     This is most useful when running threaded programs, as it is no
     longer necessary to calculate a good stack size to use for each
     thread.  This is currently only implemented for the i386 and
     x86_64 backends running GNU/Linux.

     When code compiled with -fsplit-stack calls code compiled
     without -fsplit-stack, there may not be much stack space
     available for the latter code to run.  If compiling all code,
     including library code, with -fsplit-stack is not an option,
     then the linker can fix up these calls so that the code compiled
     without -fsplit-stack always has a large stack.  Support for
     this is implemented in the gold linker in GNU binutils release 2.21
     and later.
```

The `llvm` code generation framework provides support for segmented stacks, which are used in the `go` language and were originally used in Mozilla's `rust` (although they were removed from rust on the grounds that the execution overhead is too high for a "high-performance language". (See [this mailing list thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.rust.devel/6243))

Despite the `rust`-team's objections, segmented stacks are surprisingly fast, although the stack-thrashing problem can impact particular programs. (Some `Go` programs suffer from this issue, too.)

Another mechanism for heap-allocating stack segments in a relatively efficient way was proposed by Henry Baker in his 1994 paper [Cheney on the MTA](http://home.pipeline.com/~hbaker1/CheneyMTA.html) and became the basis of the run-time for [Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org/), a compiled mostly R<sup>5</sup>RS-compatible scheme implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is certainly *not* avoided in production code -- it's just used where and when appropriate.

If you're worried about it, the right answer may not simply be to switch to a manually-maintained stack in a vector or whatever -- though you can do that -- but to reorganize the logic. For example, the compiler I was working on replaced one deep recursive process with a worklist-driven process, since there wasn't a need to maintain strict nesting in the order of processing, only to ensure that variables we had a dependency upon were computed before being used.

Answer (score 0):

If you link with a thread library (e.g. pthreads in C), each thread has a separate stack. Those stacks are allocated one way or another, ultimately (in a UNIX environment) with `brk` or an anonymous `mmap`. These might or might not use the heap on the way.

I note all the above answers refer to separate stacks; none explicitly says "on the heap" (in the C sense). I am taking it the poster simply means "from dynamically allocated memory" rather than the calling processor stack.